# I am trying to send data to my PHP page from html page using ajax POST method but it give error ,Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<head>
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#search").on("keyup", function () {
                var search_term = $(this).val();
                console.log('value--', search_term)
                $.ajax({
                    url: "ajax-live-search.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: { search: search_term },
                    success: function (ajaxresult) {
                        $("table-data").html(ajaxresult);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="search-bar">
        <label>Search</label>
        <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">
    </div>
    <div id="table-data">
    </div>
</body>
```

**PHP page**

```
$search_input = $_POST["search"];
echo $search_input;
```

**error**

> Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\ajax\ajax-live-search.php on line 3

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ `method` not `type`. here `type: "POST",`; default method is `GET` so that is current method.

Comment: what's the output of echo var_dump($_POST);

Comment: what's the output of echo var_dump($_REQUEST); should show if anything is being received by the server

Comment: You are sending a `GET` not `POST`. Please read comments, we can already see your notice, dont need it duplicated.

Comment: `$_REQUEST` includes `POST` and `GET`.. soo back to comment 1..

Comment: ...and still comment 1 would resolve your issue.. presume the latest update is `POST` output

Answer (score 1):

Change "type" to "method" as below:

```
   $.ajax({
            url: "ajax-live-search.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: { search: search_term },
            success: function (ajaxresult) {
                     $("table-data").html(ajaxresult);
                 }
           });
```